# Correct method to display Bitmap from url on ImageView that works on emulator and physical device?

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, textures, drawable

I am building an Android app for local media and parse the relevant images and such from The Movie Database API, Everything is working fine on the Android Studio emulator but when i build the apk and install on a real device none of the downloaded images are displayed on their ImageViews.

The code i am using is;

```
String Url = Actionlist1.getString(t);//pasrsed from a JSONArray object
java.net.URL url = new java.net.URL(Url);
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.connect();
InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
Bitmap b1 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, 100, 140, false);//hard coded scaling to the ImageView width and height.
ImageView B1 = findViewById(R.id.Button1);
B1.setImageBitmap(b1);
```

This code works fine when ran on the emulator but when ran on a device all images are black, i'm at a loss as the code should work and other than the image being missing the app behaves correctly.

Comment: What is the value of Url at this line `String Url = Actionlist1.getString(t)`?

Comment: I have added the solution, appears newer versions of android will only work with https not http.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
        Glide.with(this)
                    .asBitmap()
                    .load(//url)
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.vijay)
                    .into(imageView);
```

add this dependency also

    `implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'`

Comment: Unfortunately the image does not load and reverts to the fallback image when ran on the main thread and as in the onPostExecute of an async method. Any ideas on how to get this running?

Answer (score 0):

Just add this line in your app.gradle file

```
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
```

after that you can easily load your image from online.

```
Picasso.get().load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView);
```

Comment: Cheers,This Package behaves exactly the same, loads fine in the emulator but just a black image when ran on a physical device.

Comment: try to load another image from online if its works fine then find out the problem of your image

Comment: Cheers, you were partially correct it was the requirement for the use of https.

Answer (score -1):

Going to drop the answer in for any one who faces the same problem. The discrepancy between the network methods used between the Android versions, newer versions will not load image assets that did not come from a secure connection. If your facing the same issue change the URL as below;

```
//Old URL   
String URL= "http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/l4iknLOenijaB85Zyb5SxH1gGz8.jpg";
//New URL   
String URL= "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/l4iknLOenijaB85Zyb5SxH1gGz8.jpg";
```

the s really does make all the difference.